# Simple advice - Create a database

Tags: database

I'm here to ask a really simple advice to find the right system to accomplish my goal. I would like to create a simple online survey system and store the received information in spreadsheet based on some code. (So for example if Y answered X store this data in the Z spreadsheet). I'm a pretty solid C++ programmer, but I don't know how to manage a database like this. Could you help me giving me some advice? (What language to study, what online service to use...). I really don't know where to start.
Thank you very much!
Francesco.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is too broad a question to get good answers on StackOverflow. But I wanted to mention [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) in case that's sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

is quite simple, you need to have a relationship type called N-N.
A row of table X can have multiple rows in table Y. This will save you from table Z.

A very common example of this is the like of facebook. X are the users, Y are the posts and Z saves that X liked to Y

I personally recommend a database (DBMOS) called MySql which is the most common version of the SQL standard

In the case of Facebook like the correct structure to save this data is:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60910/5